# How to make the same package used for different python interpreters?

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

I install graphiz (a Python package for drawing) using brew, but when I turn to other Python interpreters, they do not recognise it. There are many Python interpreters that need to use this package, which would be time-consuming if I need to install one by one.

Is there a way to install this package once and then all the interpreters could recognise and use it?

Comment: a certain module can have version specific files and does not work with other python versions, why do you need to use many Python version, you can base the other interpreters with virtual environments based on a Python version that has a particular module installed globally

Comment: @rioV8 Another question is: does brew-installed python automatically recognise brew-installed packages? I have checked the brew-list command results for each python interpreter are the same. Is there a way to check the scope for each package installed?

Comment: Do you mean `graphviz`? -- Usually there are two pars to this. ***1.*** The actual [`graphviz`](https://www.graphviz.org/). The binary. Is not Python related. Needs to be installed once on the system. Not to be installed with pip, i.e. it is not the one on _PyPI_. ***2.*** The [`graphviz` Python binding](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/). This one is obviously about Python. This is the part that allows to use graphviz from Python code, both parts are necessary. Needs to be installed with pip. Needs to be installed once per Python interpreter and virtual environment.